# How to print a file opened inside VisioViewer activeX control using VS2005

Tags: visio

I am creating Microsoft Office Visio Viewer ActiveX control inside my View class (I am using SDI model), I have done this using an ActiveX class wrapper created by class wizard.

I am able to open a vsd file, but when I click on Print menu item, it prints a blank page.
The Visio Viewer ActiveX doesnt have any print function exposed as per the documentation, but it does mention that:-

> Microsoft Visio Viewer is an ActiveX control that lets you open, view,
>   or print Visio drawings, even if you do not have Microsoft Visio 2010.

How do I print the activeX control content from "Print" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to print the document by referring to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6940/Printing-ActiveX-Controls) and using the

PrintControlUsingScreen()